# Elasticsearch performance

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

I am running elasticsearch on my vm windows server 2008 r2. Sometimes, when I try to go to:

```
servername:9200
servername:9200/_plugin/head
servername:9200/_plugin/kibana
....
```

The server seems stucked on loading the page. I check the space disk on my vm and it's not satured, I check also the cpu and memory and all these indicators are well. So I am asking what could impact elasticsearch performance(is there some parameters that I can add or remove in elasticsearch.yaml config). It's important because we are going to use it to monitor approximatively 20 servers, and right now it's struggle with one machine. I don't know if it have an impact, but when I check elasticsearch logs, I get this line :

```
jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
```

Can someone explain me how to use the server vm. Also, I saw on internet that normally when you run on 64 bits machine, you won't have this message, but I am getting it.

Thanks in advance for your advices to optimize es.

Answer (score 0):

What java version you are using? 
Share the output of "java -version" command

E.g. java -version on my machine yields

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit **Server VM** (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

**(note "Server VM" on last line of command output)** If this is the case with you, you are good from the perspective of JVM version. You could still go back and check if you have multiple java installations, this warning is common on 32bit jdk.

Coming on to slow performance of Head plugin/kibana.

- Were you able to open the plugin even once? Are you sure installation is correct?
- Are you sure your ES nodes are slow? How did you verify apart from hitting plugin URL? *(Try curl commands to query the data)*

**Make sure the plugin version and Elastic Search version are compatible with each other**

Let me know if this helps else please share more data.

Comment: I am facing the same problem this is what I get as output for java -version


java version "1.8.0_65"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

The server vm message might be a read herring. You can still use the server by adding -server in the elasticsearch.bat file where the Java command is called.

I would probably look into the log for other problems in your logs such as memory, security permissions, etc.